# Python NLTK NER tagger - won't return ngrams longer than 1

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to extract entities from utf-8 text but cannot seem to get nltk.stanford.NERTagger to return ngrams longer than 1.

Anyone knows how to do this?

```
import nltk    
NER = nltk.stanford.NERTagger("/Library/Java/Extensions/NER/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz",
    "/Library/Java/Extensions/NER/stanford-ner.jar")

NER.tag('Game of Thrones by George R. R. Martin'.split())
```

the out put is something like this:

```
[[(u'Game', u'O'),
  (u'of', u'O'),
  (u'Thrones', u'O'),
  (u'by', u'O'),
  (u'George', u'PERSON'),
  (u'R.', u'PERSON'),
  (u'R.', u'PERSON'),
  (u'Martin', u'PERSON')]]
```

I need something like this:

```
[[(u'Game', u'O'),
  (u'of', u'O'),
  (u'Thrones', u'O'),
  (u'by', u'O'),
  (u'George R. R. Martin', u'PERSON')]]
```

A colleague of mine calls the same stanford NLP algorithm in Java and the entities are not broken down by word.

Thanks!

===== LIKELY DUPLICATE =====

[Chunking Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER) outputs from NLTK format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629130/chunking-stanford-named-entity-recognizer-ner-outputs-from-nltk-format)

Comment: minor typo in your code sample, should be `nltk.tag.stanford.StanfordNERTagger` right?

Answer (score 4):

Based on alexis' answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664677/extract-list-of-persons-and-organizations-using-stanford-ner-tagger-in-nltk),  the Stanford tagger does not expose a way to differentiate two adjacent named entities and a single named entity taking up multiple tokens.

That being said, the solution mentioned there of just chunking adjacent tokens tagged with the same entity together is often an effective heuristic (though definitely not foolproof):

```
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

result = NER.tag('Game of Thrones by George R. R. Martin'.split())
chunked = []
for tag, chunk in groupby(result, lambda x:x[1]):
    if tag == "O":
        chunked.extend((w,t) for (w,t) in chunk)
    else:
        chunked.append((" ".join(w for (w,t) in chunk), tag))
pprint(chunked)
```

Gives output:

```
[(u'Game', u'O'),
 (u'of', u'O'),
 (u'Thrones', u'O'),
 (u'by', u'O'),
 (u'George R. R. Martin', u'PERSON')]
```